# ReactJS: Handle Failed Load Resource in Production Build

Tags: reactjs

Is there any better handling error when user failed load css resource in React?

I have already wrap all `Lazy Page` with some Component that working with ComponentDidcatch, when I Block css resource url, ComponentDidcatch wont catch anything except I block chunk.js url.

its hard to reproduce this bug, but I have hypothesis that user having bad internet connection.

Comment: Please provide a little more information on what resources do you mean. Which resources are you referring to? Are they external css files being fetched from a CDN or are local css files that you have bundled with your app. Are you using a module bundler for this? Can you check if that bundler can provide you with error handling?